# Checking to see if an array 3x3 is all not a certain character?

Tags: c

```
bool check_table_full(char board[SIZE][SIZE]) {
  for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++) {

      if (board[i][j] == '_')
        return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

I am trying to return true if all elements are NOT an underscore but this code isn't working properly and behaving undefined, and I am lost.

```
bool check_end_of_game(char board[SIZE][SIZE]){
if (check_three_in_a_row(board)!=0 || check_table_full(board) == true) 
return true;
else
return false;

}
```

Comment: *"... code isn't working properly and behaving undefined"* could you describe the exact problem you are seeing?

Comment: How exactly is it behaving undefined? What error are you seeing. Also, please post the calling code as your declaration of the board you pass in might be the issue.

Comment: If you are passing a ***fully initialized*** `board` array to your function, your function will work as you describe.

Comment: Initialization doesn't really matter.  The function is going to take the pointer input and walk memory looking for that underscore  It's more likely that the parameter passed is incorrect.  An actual functional example would show this.

Comment: Post a [mcve]..

Comment: Um it's just not returning true when the array is full

Comment: like the thing is always returning false

Comment: @Rich - initialization DOES matter, if `board` is not fully initialized `if (board[i][j] == '_')` accesses an *indeterminate* value invoking *Undefined Behavior*. [C11 Standard - J.2 Undefined behavior](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#J.2) *"The value of an object with automatic storage duration is used while it is indeterminate (6.2.4, 6.7.9, 6.8).*"

Comment: board is initialized as char

Comment: @steakfry: pls post code where you initialize the array and call the function `check_table_full`

Comment: ok i post it now

Comment: You may want to check [Helpful Hints for You](http://paste.opensuse.org/91387032) for determining row-value-winner, etc.. (this is similar to another recent question)

Comment: You still do not show the initialization of the array. Also there is no definition.

Comment: When you run it in a debugger, at which index does the function detect an `'_'` that should not be there?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin In the context he's given us, it doesn't.  "Undefined" is exactly what you'll get, but that doesn't mean the code will do something random.  It just means that it *might* see an underscore where he doesn't intend there to be one.  Bottom line, this question has received way more attention than it should given the lack of context.

Comment: I agree with you. It is the old -- what happens after undefined behavior is invoked conundrum. In this case, there is a comparison between (1) some indeterminate value and (2) an `'_'`. But then there is the whole standard view of undefined behavior and where the defined execution of your code ends. The standard simply says once undefined behavior is invoked -- all bets are off. It doesn't get into shades or severity of undefined behavior -- and that is the correct approach. You and I both know here, it is either equal or it isn't, but splitting undefined behavior hairs, just ain't worth it.